# microsoft.ace.oledb logging and difference between 12 vs 16

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I have random issues with `microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0` so i'm looking for a solution.

So:

1. What are the improvement of `microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0`? I tried to search comparison between 12.0 and 16.0 but I fined nothing.
2. For the same reason, does `microsoft.ace.oledb` logs his errors somewhere on the server?

The errors occurs when I write data from T-SQL to Excel via openrowset, usually in two different situations.

- Sometimes, when I write data to an Excel (in 5 different sheets), the operation fails. Repeating the write operation, it succeded;
- Sometimes, when I have two parallel tasks who are writing data to an Excel, one or both tasks fail.

The T-SQL query used is a dynamic query for query composing reasons, and it is:

> EXEC (
>
> 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel
> 12.0;Database=\SERVER\filename.xlsx'',
> ''Select * from [Foglio1$]'')
>
> SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM dbo.mytable
>
> ');

About the error, from MS-SQL I got only the usual standard message, that explains nothing. The message is:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0" for linked server "(null)".

Thanks.

Comment: the driver isn't supported in sql server linked server / openrowset scenarios, it's for gui usage only, so the best would be to move away from it and use something else

Comment: I would suggest that `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0` is neither version 12 nor version 16.

Comment: @siggemannen which is your suggestion for write data from SQL SERVER to Excel? I change my post to add the T-SQL syntax used

Comment: Write data from somewhere else, there are libs for powershell, java, c# and probably assembler to read and write excel files to a database